# How to I enable c3p0 logging within my hibernate class

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0, java.util.logging

I am using Java 8, Hibernate 4.3.11 and c3p0 9.2.1.

I define all my c3p0 properties from within my hibernate config class

e.g

```
  Configuration config = new org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration();
  config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection","50");
```

this works great because it means everything works the same on different platforms (Mac, Windows, Linux, Docker etc)

But I could not get any c3p0 debugging output, I had some success by adding

```
-Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog
```

but using

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.c3p0.com.mchange.v2.log.MLog","com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.Jdk14MLog");
```

instead has no effect.

Is it possible because adding as a system properties would require modification to build scripts for all platforms (we provided proper installers not just a jar file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [com.mchange.v2.log.MLog.refreshConfig(null, null)](https://github.com/swaldman/mchange-commons-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mchange/v2/log/MLog.java) after you set the config property.

One issue with setting on the command line vs. setting at run time is that class loading often triggers the read of the property.  Which means that at run time the value is read before it is set by your code.

Comment: Thanks, but I cant find such method ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor I linked to the source code.  It appears to be a public static method.  Maybe that source code doesn't match the version you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I think it was because I dont directly reference c3p0 in my pom, it only gets pulled in as part of Hibernate. been doing some reading and found that I should be setting up logging config via specifying  -Djava.util.logging.config.class at startup and if I do this and strip back my class I can get c3p0 to work, trouble is some of the code in class currently refers to unitilialized stuff

Comment: c3p0-0.9.2.1 is pretty old. as @jmehrens says, the logging and config libraries c3p0 uses were originally built around static variables initialized on classloading. the ability to refresh / change those initialized values was added later. you could try bringing in a newer version of `mchange-commons-java` (the dependency where all that stuff lives), or better yet, update to a more current `c3p0`.

Comment: Right thanks, my issue is im using the one embedded with Hibernate 4.3.11. I need to move to a later version of Hibernate but that is potentially sizeable task